# Background of div section has unexplained padding, Why?

Tags: php, html, css, background, padding

Ok, ive spent a few days trying to figure out why this isnt working, and so far Google has gave me nothing of use. Maybe there is a built in rule that I just am not aware of. I hate posting on sites like this with questions that could be trivial but ive exhausted my own efforts.

So I have placed a background in my CSS and it works on the alotted tag, but it is adding some padding that is not specified. Trying to change it does nothing. The background for the body stretches the duration of the screen but not this one.

**Here is where the header is being included.**

```
<?php
    require_once 'classes/Membership.php';
    $membership = new Membership();
    $loggedin = $membership->confirm_loggedin();
    if(!$loggedin){
        ob_start();
        header("Location: http://lolteamrecruiter.com/login.php");
        ob_end_flush();    
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

include @ 'header.php';

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="Login">

        <!--LOGOUT BUTTON -->
        <p>
            Results Page
        </p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the php file being included.**

```
<link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="header">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="css/images/angel.png" height="40px" width="20px"></a> 

    <?php
    require_once 'classes/Membership.php';
    $membership = new Membership();
    $loggedin = $membership->confirm_loggedin();
    if($loggedin){
        echo '    <div id="header-right-account">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">My Account</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tacos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Burritos</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://lolteamrecruiter.com/login.php?status=logout">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>';

    }else{
     echo '<div id="header-right"><a href="login.php">Log In</a></div>';

    }
    ?>


</div>
```

**This is the css file thats applying the background**

```
#header{

    background-image : url(images/black.png); 
    background-repeat : no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment : fixed;  
    background-origin:border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    top:0;

}
```

The site to see this is at http://lolteamrecruiter.com/

Comment: Are you using any CSS resets?

Comment: If you by some padding mean space around header than try `html,body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%`.

Comment: Agreed, this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the spacing around the logo? Just add display:block to the image.

Edit

Okay, add margin:0 to the body.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I want the black header to go all the way to the sides of the screen, and all the way to the top of the screen. Theres space on both sides and top thats white(from the body background).

Comment: Yay, tyvm. I knew it was something stupid and obvious. Is it because by default the body is providing a margin, even though the header comes before the body tags?

Comment: It depends on the browser, Chrome adds 8px :)

Answer (score 0):

Your image is aligned to the baseline by default, which means that gap below it is space for the lower part of letters like p, g, j, etc.

Try this:

```
#header a img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background-image : url(images/login-box-backg2.png) no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment : fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```